# Holographic dualities with a QFT with a mass gap

Tags: quantum-field-theory, holographic-principle

The original holographic duality AdS/CFT points to a *conformal* field theory in the boundary. CFTs do not have a mass gap and all mass spectra are allowed

Are there any existing examples of holographic dualities to a Quantum Field Theory in the boundary that have well-defined mass gaps?